# How to show and hide Div by mutiple Select form after submission

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have two select form with submit button, I need to get the result of selected value for example

first select form having colours as an option and second contains another things.

and i have some items as div....red flower , red fish.

if i select red from first form its shows red value div and in second form if i select flower it should display red flower only but it's shows everything under the value red. And these all thing must work only when i submit the search button.
I have attached jsfiddle below.
Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("select").change(function(){
        $(this).find("option:selected").each(function(){
            var optionValue = $(this).attr("value");
            if(optionValue){
                $(".box").not("." + optionValue).hide();
                $("." + optionValue).show();
            } else{
                $(".box").hide();
            }
        });
    }).change();
});
```

```css
.box{
        color: #fff;
        padding: 20px;
        display: none;
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
    .red{ background: #ff0000; }
    .green{ background: #228B22; }
    .blue{ background: #0000ff; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
      <div class="col-5">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="red">Red</option>
            <option value="green">Green</option>
            <option value="blue">Blue</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-5">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="all">All</option>
            <option value="flower">flower</option>
            <option value="fish">fish</option>
            <option value="toy">toy</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      <div class="col-2">
        <button id="search" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Search</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    <div class="red all flower box">Red flower</div>
    <div class="red all fish box">red fish</div>
    <div class="green all toy box">green toy</div>
    <div class="blue all toy box">blue toy</div>
    <div class="blue all flower box">blue flower</div>
```

Jsfiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/JOHN_748/v846oeab/1/

Comment: You've described your code well, but what exactly is the problem/s you're facing?

Comment: if i select an option from my first select form means its showing right value but when i make changes to my second select form its not showing correctly. please check my fiddle output there you will understand my issue well

Comment: Need to do the change event on the new value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45722487/change-select-value-with-jquery#45722794

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. get the select's values which are the classes you are looking for
2. toggle the boxes that have both classes

If you have more selection criteria, we should loop, but here we just look at class1 and class2

```js
$(function() {
  const $sels = $("select");
  const $boxes = $(".box");
  $("#search").on("click", function() {
    const vals = $sels.map(function() { return this.value }).get()
    $boxes.each(function() { 
      const show = $(this).hasClass(vals[0]) && $(this).hasClass(vals[1]);
      $(this).toggle(show) 
    });
  }).click();
});
```

```css
.box {
  color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  display: none;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.red {
  background: #ff0000;
}

.green {
  background: #228B22;
}

.blue {
  background: #0000ff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-5">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="red">Red</option>
      <option value="green">Green</option>
      <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5">
    <select class="form-control">
      <option value="all">All</option>
      <option value="flower">flower</option>
      <option value="fish">fish</option>
      <option value="toy">toy</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="col-2">
    <button id="search" class="btn btn-primary w-100">Search</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="red all flower box">Red flower</div>
<div class="red all fish box">red fish</div>
<div class="green all toy box">green toy</div>
<div class="blue all toy box">blue toy</div>
<div class="blue all flower box">blue flower</div>
```

Comment: no when if my input is ( red, flower ) then i want my  output as red flower div alone. but in output blue flower also there.

Comment: Thanks @mplungjan brother :)

Comment: Hey how can i implement onclick method for your method, i wanted to get results after i clicked my search button. Can you pls tell that!!

Comment: Trivial. Perhaps look at the jQuery site? See update

Comment: Okay! Working :)

Comment: I cleaned it up a little. Made it more readable